# Is there a difference in WPF layout between Win8 and older versions of Windows?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-8

We're upgrading to newer development boxes at work. They came with Windows 7 on them. I had been planning on upgrading mine to Windows 8. However, this [article on LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Odd-WPF-behavior-on-Windows-43315.S.151387424?qid=8eb87058-b69b-433f-b59c-c0c184382b43&trk=group_search_item_list-0-b-ttl) really has me concerned, because we've got to do some WPF development. Is there a difference in layout in Windows 8 vs. older versions of Windows, when it comes to doing WPF development?

Comment: I don't see the link to the article, the current link redirects me to a discussion forum. As for the issue, it sounds like it could be similar to the radio button rendering issue on different DPIs in Windows 8. The DPI issue basically causes the alignment to be slightly off for radiobuttons,. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758368/radio-button-rendering-is-incorrect-on-windows-8-with-125-dpi-scaling-set

Comment: You are correct, I linked to the discussion on LinkedIn, which is where I saw the issue brought up. I've not seen it elsewhere, after searching for it, so I thought I'd ask here, in case someone has seen this behavior. It's important enough that I have to know before proceeding with Win8 or staying with Win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you layout the controls properly, using vertical/horizontal aligment, that problem described on linkedin wont happen at all.
I started developing WPF on windows 8, so i got used quickly to controls not being where i originally i wanted them to be, which i inherited from winforms.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, using alignment properties the behavior isn't seen at all. But if we pad a control using units of space, and do that with other controls as well to align those controls up, then what you see in Windows XP/Vista/7 isn't necessarily what you'll see in Windows 8 desktop mode. Correct?

Comment: Correct.
At least, thats what i experienced.

Every single one of my controls need an alignment and/or margin properly set or it will move all over the place.

When i need controls to be set in a specific spot i need to create multiple grids and place them inside or they wont be where i want them to be. Grid rows/columns help with that.

The application im working on so far was consistent with the layout coded on windows 8, using windows 7, windows 2003 and windows 2008. I havent tried on XP or vista though.